# An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' on openshift

Tags: jenkins, openshift

I enabled Jenkins on my openshift app today. I logged in on jenkins url, but did not change any config settings. Later today I was trying to `$ git push` new version of my site. But I got following error:

```
$ git push origin
Counting objects: 17, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 917 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Executing Jenkins build.
remote: 
remote: You can track your build at https://jenkins-namespace.rhcloud.com/job/app-build
remote: 
remote: Waiting for build to schedule......
remote: **BUILD FAILED/CANCELLED**
remote: Please see the Jenkins log for more details via 'rhc tail'
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: Deployment Halted!
remote: If the build failed before the deploy step, your previous
remote: build is still running.  Otherwise, your application may be
remote: partially deployed or inaccessible.
remote: Fix the build and try again.
remote: !!!!!!!!
remote: An error occurred executing 'gear postreceive' (exit code: 1)
remote: Error message: CLIENT_ERROR: Failed to execute: 'control post-receive' for /var/lib/openshift/52UUID/jenkins-client
remote: 
remote: For more details about the problem, try running the command again with the '--trace' option.
To ssh://52UUID@app-namespace.rhcloud.com/~/git/app.git/
   6a9fe46..a551871  master -> master
```

so I ran `$rhc tail jenkins`:

```
Jul 10, 2015 2:43:45 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud hasCapacity
INFO: No capacity remaining.  Not provisioning...
Jul 10, 2015 2:43:45 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provisionSlave
INFO: Not provisioning new builder due to lack of capacity
Jul 10, 2015 2:43:45 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud provision
INFO: Provisioned 0 new nodes
Jul 10, 2015 2:43:45 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
INFO: Cancelling Item 
Jul 10, 2015 2:43:45 PM hudson.plugins.openshift.OpenShiftCloud cancelItem
WARNING: Build app-build appbldr has been canceled
```

So I guess I have lack of capacity. So I check `$ rhc show-app app --gears quota`:

```
 Gear                     Cartridges                                            Used Limit
------------------------ --------------------------------------------------- ------ -----
52UUID python-2.7 postgresql-9.2 cron-1.4 jenkins-client-1 0.9 GB  1 GB
```

0.9GB out of 1GB. I already deleted logs and ran rhc tidy command. My latest db backup had 14MB (two days ago, have not tested if it's full though) and my app has 35MB in files, images, js libraries etc.
**I do not want to deal with capacity problem here, rather how much does jenkins push need to be successful?**
I am a student and I use openshift for a student project, so I would like to avoid upgrade at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `No capacity remaining.` means I have 3/3 gears, not disk usage. [More info.](https://forums.openshift.com/jenkins-cant-build)